# Python Gaussian Quadrature and the Trapezoid rule Integral error

Tags: python

[image: QUESTION DETAILS]

Been trying to do this python. Question details are in the image link

Am getting this error when running the program

Any help is appreciated

```
   File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/tapez.py", line 9, in exactIntegral
     integral = ((4(math.cos(0.4*b)** 2)) * ((5(math.exp( -0.5 * b))) +

 TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here is the code

```
import math
import numpy
import scipy.integrate.quadrature as quad

def fun(x):
    return x*numpy.sin(x)

def exactIntegral(a, b):
    integral = (((9)+4(math.cos(0.4*b)** 2)) * ((5(math.exp( -0.5 * b))) +
                 (2(math.exp( 0.15 * b)))))+ (((9)+4(math.cos(0.4*a)** 2)) * 
                ((5(math.exp( -0.5 * a))) + (2(math.exp( 0.15 * a)))))

    return integral

a = 0.0
b = 8.0

exact = exactIntegral(a, b)
estimate = quad(fun,a,b)
print("Gaussian Quadrature: ", exact)

# Trapazoid Rule
n = 100
h = (b-a)/(n-1)
x = numpy.linspace(a,b,num=n)
area = 0
for i in range(n-1):
    area = area + h*(fun(x[i]) + fun(x[i+1]))/2.0
print("Trapazoid rule: ", area)
```

Comment: ``5(math.exp`` should probably be ``5 * (math.exp``, same with other places where you omitted the ``*``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
integral = (((9)+4(math.cos(0.4*b)** 2)) * ((5(math.exp( -0.5 * b))) +
                 (2(math.exp( 0.15 * b)))))+ (((9)+4(math.cos(0.4*a)** 2)) * 
                ((5(math.exp( -0.5 * a))) + (2(math.exp( 0.15 * a))))
```

Python does not interpret things like `2(x+1)` as `2*(x+1)` automatically. You need to specify the multiplication operator `*` explicitly.

For Python `2()` is a function call of a function named `2`. But `2` is an int object and it cannot be called like a function